# Detect remote port in IHttpHandler

Tags: c#, endpoint, ihttphandler

Hey how do you get the remote port for a request on the web server?

So my code should look like this:

```
public class EndpointReflectionHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public new void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string address = context.Request.UserHostAddress;
        int port = context.Request.UserHostPort;            //it's not there

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write(address + ":" + port);
    }
}
```

..but I can't find anything to get the port.

EDIT. Thanks to Tim for great comment:

Here's the full workflow:

1. Client starts, opens a socket
2. Hey webservice what's my IP and port?
3. It's 1.2.3.4:1234
4. Hey other person, I'll listen on 1.2.3.4:1234 (even though to me it looks like 9.9.9.9:9999
5. OK man I'll connect to 1.2.3.4:1234
6. Everyone happy, have a beer

Comment: What would you do with that information if you had it?  You can't communicate with that port.   In virtually every case today, that's a NAT port that only has meaning within the connection.  You can try `context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_PORT"]`, but it won't do you much good.

Comment: Hey Tim. Precisely, it's NAT. So my client software doesn't know what port it is even using.. although the IP address is available. How would you tackle that?

Comment: Check https://www.myip.com/ it has remote port. So why doesn't C# have that ability?

Comment: Your workflow doesn't make sense.  Who do you think is going to listen on 1.2.3.4:1234?  That IP maps to a gateway router somewhere.  It invented port number 1234 for that specific outbound HTTP connection, and when there's traffic on that port from the connection it made, it forwards it internally.  Other traffic on that port is tossed.  You can't open a new connection to it.

Comment: Nah brah. a bidirectional socket. It uses the same socket for a quick webmethod call to get the port number. then keep it open so others can connect to it. otherwise how da hell can it know it's own port? nat would screw it up and never tells you (in C# at least) what the external port number is....

Comment: Hang on.  Are you trying to say (1) client 192.168.x.x connects to server through NAT, (2) server sees 1.2.3.4:1234, reports that to client, (3) client opens new socket listening on 1.2.3.4:1234, (4) server does a connect on 1.2.3.4:1234 and reaches the client?  That's a huge NAT failure -- it's not how NAT is supposed to work.  No one from the outside should ever be able to initiate a connection to a machine inside the firewall without explicit port forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

I got it context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_PORT"].

There's nothing about it, just guesswork and looking everywhere :)

Comment: You could also credit Tim Roberts who originally suggested this in the comments of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the port with this line:

```
int port = new Uri(request.UserHostAddress).Port;
```